# How to delete the weird blue underline

Tags: css

As I mention in title, I can't find what's wrong and I don't even know why there is a blue line while the pointer hover on. 
DEMO: https://anniesnoopymd.github.io/web-final-project/dist/new.html

```
<div class="line">─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ 登入安全(至少要有一種安全判斷) ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─</div>
```

```
.line {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fc3f64;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  text-decoraion:none;
}
.line:hover {
  text-decoraion:none;
}
```

Comment: This question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic) because it does not include a [mcve]. Links to external sites are not appropriate as they may change rendering the question useless to future visitors.

Comment: I just found a nice site, http://csslint.net/, which when fed your CSS says: `Unknown property 'text-decoraion'.` twice. You're missing a `t`.

Comment: Additionally, looking at the site in question, you have invalid markup, with an `<a>` element that wraps all of your content. Hovering over anything on that page triggers the `text-decoration` on the `<a>`

Comment: @zzzzBov I didn't look closely enough to see that - but that *would* be a contributing problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default">全部欄位<a>
```

you should close the a tag:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default">全部欄位</a>
```

Please consider to use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fanniesnoopymd.github.io%2Fweb-final-project%2Fdist%2Fnew.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) when coding because there are other unclosed tags and problems in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.line:active
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find issue and then fix it:
Your whole code is wrapped inside  tag which caused every thing to be underlined.

See this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIWuJmCDI1va0VRRWp4UThvS0k/view?usp=sharing

You can remove this `<a>` tag fix this. Or use following CSS to fix this

```
a:hover, a:active{
   text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

if this does not work use `a:hover *, a:active *` also

Answer (score 0):

After checking your code, you need to override the default `<a>` tag, which as `text-decoration: underline;`. Also, I'm not sure you should contain your form in a `<a>`.

```
a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #158cba;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in picture, the a tag, have some defualt value come from your bootstrap when hover occurred. So, you can fix this with adding a class to this  tag and override the bootstrap style hover. for example, if you change you  tag and add a class like :

```
<a class="overrideStyle">
```

and in your css :

```
 .overrideStyle{ text-decoration: none; }
```

it will fix the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in your code, 
change

```
text-decoraion:none
```

to

```
 {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

if it doesnt work, use a more specific query selector, (giving the div an 'id' would do)